# tkinter canvas repeats creating new frame

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, canvas

In my Tkinter GUI widget, the submit button commands to draw a plot on a designated frame (plotframe). Initially, the canvas code, and the navigation toolbar work. However, every time I press the submit button, the frame expands and a new graph is created rather than plotting in the same assigned area.

How can I modify the code so that the plot is updated on itself?
In addition, the save option of the navigation toolbar only saves the plot not the whole content of the frame. Would it possible to arrange it to save the plot and its associated text?

I appreciate it if anyone helps me to resolve the two issues.

All the best,
Payman

'''

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
from matplotlib.backends._backend_tk import NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


def main ():
    root = Tk()
    w , h = root.winfo_screenwidth() , root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w , h))
    root.resizable(width=True , height=True)
    root.title("Form")
    root.configure(bg='Dodgerblue4')
    root.state('zoomed')

    top_frame = Frame(root , bg='Dodgerblue4' ,borderwidth=2, bd=1, relief= SUNKEN, pady=10)
    frameX = Frame(root , bg='Dodgerblue4' ,borderwidth=2, bd=1 , relief=SUNKEN, padx = 15, pady = 10)
    frameY = Frame(root , bg='Dodgerblue4' ,borderwidth=2, bd=1 , relief=SUNKEN, padx = 15, pady = 10)
    submitframe = Frame(root , bg='Dodgerblue4' ,borderwidth=2, bd=1 , relief=SUNKEN)
    plotframe = Frame(root , bg='Dodgerblue4' ,borderwidth=2, bd=1 , relief=SUNKEN)
    # plotframe = Canvas(root , bg='Dodgerblue4' ,borderwidth=2, bd=1 , relief=SUNKEN)


    top_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew", columnspan= 20)
    top_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0 , weight=1)
    frameX.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="nsew", columnspan = 2, rowspan = 6)
    frameY.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky="nsew", columnspan = 2, rowspan = 16)
    submitframe.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky="nsew", rowspan = 22)
    submitframe.grid_rowconfigure(0 , weight=1)

    plotframe.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky="nsew", rowspan = 22, columnspan = 17 )
    plotframe.grid_rowconfigure(0 , weight=1)
    plotframe.grid_columnconfigure(0 , weight=1)

    label_top = Label(top_frame , text="Design Page" , font=('' , '15' , ''), bg='Dodgerblue4' ,  fg='white', justify=CENTER).grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan= 20)

   # ------------------------------------------Xs-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    X1 = Label(frameX, text='X1', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky = W)
    X2 = Label(frameX, text='X2', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky = W)
    X3 = Label(frameX, text='X3', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky = W)
    X4 = Label(frameX, text='X4', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky = W)
    X5 = Label(frameX, text='X5', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky = W)
    X6 = Label(frameX, text='X6', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky = W)
    # -------------------------------------------Ys--------------------------------------------------------------------
    label_spec = Label(frameY, text='the parameters', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan = 2)
    Y1 = Label(frameY, text='Y1', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 1, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y2 = Label(frameY, text='Y2', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 2, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y3 = Label(frameY, text='Y3', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 3, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y4 = Label(frameY, text='Y4', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 4, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y5 = Label(frameY, text='Y5', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 5, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y6 = Label(frameY, text='Y6', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 6, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y7 = Label(frameY, text='Y7', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 7, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y8 = Label(frameY, text='Y8', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 8, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y9 = Label(frameY, text='Y9', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 9, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y10 = Label(frameY, text='Y10', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 10, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y11 = Label(frameY, text='Y11', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 11, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y12 = Label(frameY, text='Y12', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 12, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y13 = Label(frameY, text='Y13', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 13, column= 0, sticky = W)

    def todo():
        x = [-100 , 100]
        y = [0 , 4]
        fig = plt.figure( facecolor='#104e8b' , edgecolor='k', figsize=(9,6))
        gs = fig.add_gridspec(13 , 7 , top=1)

        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:8 , 0:5])
        ax1.plot(x , y , 'b-' , label=' Profile 1')
        plt.xlabel(' x1 (mm) ' , color='w')
        plt.ylabel(' y1 (mm)' , color='w')
        plt.legend(loc='lower left')

        ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:12 , 5:6])
        ax2.text(0.05 , 0.95 ,
                 "The  Specifications: \n Y1 \n\n Y2, \n\n Y3, \n\n Y4, \n\n Y5,\n\n Y6, \n\n Y7, \n\n Y8, "
                 "\n\n Y9,\n\n Y10, \n\n Y11, \n\n Y12, \n\n Y13",
                 style='normal' , color='w' , fontsize=10 ,transform=ax2.transAxes, va='top',
                 bbox={'facecolor': 'blue' , 'alpha': 0. , 'pad': 10}
                 )
        ax2.axis('off')

        ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[8:12 , 0:5])
        ax3.plot(x , y , 'b-' , label=' Profile 2')
        plt.xlabel(' x2 (mm) ' , fontsize=10 , color='w')
        plt.ylabel(' y2 (mm)' , fontsize=10 , color='w')

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig , master=plotframe)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=BOTH , expand=1)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas , plotframe)
        toolbar.config(background='Dodgerblue4')
        toolbar._message_label.config(background='Dodgerblue4')
        toolbar.update()
        canvas.draw()


    submit_button = Button(submitframe , text='Submit' , command=todo , font=('' , '12' , '') , padx=10 , relief=RIDGE ,
                           activebackground='green' , bg='orange' , bd=5)
    submit_button.grid(row=0 , column=0 , rowspan=10 , ipady=10)
    submit_button.flash()
    submit_button.invoke()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

'''

Comment: You create a new `plt.figure()` whenever `todo()` is called.  You should create it once at the first call of `todo()` and update the plot in later calls.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you mean to place plt.figure() a line before todo() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the figure, canvas, and navigation toolbar should be defined before calling the function todo() and keep canvas.draw() inside the function.
Here is the working code:

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends._backend_tk import NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


def main ():
    root = Tk()
    w , h = root.winfo_screenwidth() , root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w , h))
    root.resizable(width=True , height=True)
    root.title("Form")
    root.configure(bg='Dodgerblue4')
    root.state('zoomed')

    top_frame = Frame(root , bg='Dodgerblue4' ,borderwidth=2, bd=1, relief= SUNKEN, pady=10)
    frameX = Frame(root , bg='Dodgerblue4' ,borderwidth=2, bd=1 , relief=SUNKEN, padx = 15, pady = 10)
    frameY = Frame(root , bg='Dodgerblue4' ,borderwidth=2, bd=1 , relief=SUNKEN, padx = 15, pady = 10)
    submitframe = Frame(root , bg='Dodgerblue4' ,borderwidth=2, bd=1 , relief=SUNKEN)
    plotframe = Frame(root , bg='Dodgerblue4' ,borderwidth=2, bd=1 , relief=SUNKEN)

    top_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew", columnspan= 20)
    top_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0 , weight=1)
    frameX.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="nsew", columnspan = 2, rowspan = 6)
    frameY.grid(column=0, row=7, sticky="nsew", columnspan = 2, rowspan = 16)
    submitframe.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky="nsew", rowspan = 22)
    submitframe.grid_rowconfigure(0 , weight=1)

    plotframe.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky="nsew", rowspan = 22, columnspan = 17 )
    plotframe.grid_rowconfigure(0 , weight=1)
    plotframe.grid_columnconfigure(0 , weight=1)

    label_top = Label(top_frame , text="Design Page" , font=('' , '15' , ''), bg='Dodgerblue4' ,  fg='white', justify=CENTER).grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan= 20)

   # ------------------------------------------Xs-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    X1 = Label(frameX, text='X1', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky = W)
    X2 = Label(frameX, text='X2', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky = W)
    X3 = Label(frameX, text='X3', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky = W)
    X4 = Label(frameX, text='X4', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky = W)
    X5 = Label(frameX, text='X5', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky = W)
    X6 = Label(frameX, text='X6', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky = W)
    # -------------------------------------------Ys--------------------------------------------------------------------
    label_spec = Label(frameY, text='the parameters', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan = 2)
    Y1 = Label(frameY, text='Y1', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 1, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y2 = Label(frameY, text='Y2', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 2, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y3 = Label(frameY, text='Y3', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 3, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y4 = Label(frameY, text='Y4', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 4, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y5 = Label(frameY, text='Y5', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 5, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y6 = Label(frameY, text='Y6', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 6, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y7 = Label(frameY, text='Y7', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 7, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y8 = Label(frameY, text='Y8', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 8, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y9 = Label(frameY, text='Y9', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 9, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y10 = Label(frameY, text='Y10', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 10, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y11 = Label(frameY, text='Y11', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 11, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y12 = Label(frameY, text='Y12', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 12, column= 0, sticky = W)
    Y13 = Label(frameY, text='Y13', fg='white', bg='Dodgerblue4', font=('' , '12' , ''), justify=CENTER).grid(row= 13, column= 0, sticky = W)
    
    fig = plt.figure(facecolor='#104e8b' , edgecolor='k' , figsize=(10 , 6))
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig , master=plotframe)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=BOTH , expand=1)
    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas , plotframe)
    toolbar.config(background='Dodgerblue4')
    toolbar._message_label.config(background='Dodgerblue4')

    def todo():
        plt.clf()
        x = [-100 , 100]
        y = [0 , 4]
        gs = fig.add_gridspec(13 , 7 , top=1)
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:8 , 0:5])
        ax1.plot(x , y , 'b-' , label=' Profile 1')
        plt.xlabel(' x1 (mm) ' , color='w')
        plt.ylabel(' y1 (mm)' , color='w')
        plt.legend(loc='lower left')

        ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:12 , 5:6])
        ax2.text(0.05 , 0.95 ,
                 "The  Specifications: \n Y1 \n\n Y2, \n\n Y3, \n\n Y4, \n\n Y5,\n\n Y6, \n\n Y7, \n\n Y8, "
                 "\n\n Y9,\n\n Y10, \n\n Y11, \n\n Y12, \n\n Y13",
                 style='normal' , color='w' , fontsize=10 ,transform=ax2.transAxes, va='top',
                 bbox={'facecolor': 'blue' , 'alpha': 0. , 'pad': 10}
                 )
        ax2.axis('off')

        ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[8:12 , 0:5])
        ax3.plot(x , y , 'b-' , label=' Profile 2')
        plt.xlabel(' x2 (mm) ' , fontsize=10 , color='w')
        plt.ylabel(' y2 (mm)' , fontsize=10 , color='w')

    toolbar.update()
    canvas.draw()


    submit_button = Button(submitframe , text='Submit' , command=todo , font=('' , '12' , '') , padx=10 , relief=RIDGE ,
                           activebackground='green' , bg='orange' , bd=5)
    submit_button.grid(row=0 , column=0 , rowspan=10 , ipady=10)
    submit_button.flash()
    submit_button.invoke()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]